# Normal to RPN conversion

Tags: algorithm, notation, rpn

I have a question.
Is `(3+4)*(5+6+7*8)*(1*9+2*8)` equal to `34 + 56 + 78 + * + 19 * 28 * + *` in RPN notation?

Comment: No. What is `34 +` supposed to do in RPN? Also, `3+4` is __never__ equal to `34` in any notation I know of.

Comment: So how should I write it?

Comment: Start by adding some spaces.

Comment: No, those aren't equal. `34+` puts `7` on the stack. `56+` puts `11` on the stack. `78+` puts `15` on the stack. That where it starts to go wrong, because it's supposed to be `7*8`, not `7+8`.

Answer (score 0):

There are these issues with your attempt:

- Numbers need to be separated by spaces as otherwise you create new numbers. `34` is thirty four, not three and then four. So write `3 4`
- The input has 5 multiplications, yet your RPN has only 4, so that cannot be right. Notably you have mixed the operators up right after the `7`. That `7` is the operand of a multiplication, not an addition. After the `7` should not have `+ * +`, but `* + *`

You can apply these steps to produce RPN:

1. Add parentheses to the input so to make all operations *binary* (with two operands only), resolving precedence (`*` has precedence over `+`), and when precedence is equal, applying a left-associativity rule:

   ```
   (3+4)*(5+6+7*8)*(1*9+2*8)
   ```

   becomes:

   ```
   ((3+4)*((5+6)+(7*8)))*((1*9)+(2*8))
   ```
2. Write the expression as a binary tree

   ```
           ______*_____
          /            \
       __*__           _+_
      /     \         /   \
     +      _+_      *     *
    / \    /   \    / \   / \
   3   4  +     *  1   9 2   8
         / \   / \
        5   6 7   8
   ```
3. Produce the output from a post order traversal, using space as separator

   ```
   3 4 + 5 6 + 7 8 * + * 1 9 * 2 8 * + *
   ```

That's it.

#### Shunting-yard

A good algorithm to convert the input to RPN is the [Shunting-year algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting_yard_algorithm). Here is an implementation in JavaScript for just the operators your expression uses:

```js
function shuntingYard(expr) {
    const precedence = {"+": 0, "*": 1, "(": -1};
    const operators = [];
    const output = [];
    
    for (const token of expr.match(/\d+|\S/g)) {
        if (token == ")") {
            while (operators.at(-1) != "(") {
                output.push(operators.pop());
            }
            operators.pop();
        } else if (token in precedence) {
            const prio = precedence[token];
            while (prio >= 0 && prio <= precedence[operators.at(-1)]) {
                output.push(operators.pop());
            }
            operators.push(token);
        } else { // It is a number
            output.push(token);
        }
    }
    return output.concat(operators).join(" ");
}

let expr = "(3+4)*(5+6+7*8)*(1*9+2*8)";
console.log(shuntingYard(expr));
```